# Weka - Threshold curve and accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am using Weka to do deal with binary classification.I used J48 classifier and the result in explorer shows 82.41% accuracy with recall=0.824 ,precision=1.0 and F-measure=0.904. 
But when I analyzed the threshold curve, it is found that at a different threshold its giving a 100% accuracy. So what does this mean?
If at a different threshold full accuracy is obtained, why Weka is outputting the other accuracy.I am confused on this point.Can we get the cutoff(of the feature value used) used by J48 classifier at different threshold points?.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What exactly is the threshold curve? Do you mean the ROC curve?

Comment: Yes.. ROC curve. In Weka it is given as: Weka Classifier Visualize:Threshold Curve.